# Unable to access property of data through BehaviorSubject. Property does not exist on BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject, subject

While using BehaviourSubject to set shared data across my application, I am unable to access the properties of the data. Getting error :-

**

> property does not exist on type 'BehaviourSubject'

**

***SharedService.ts***

```
setCommonData(data): void {
  this.commonData.next(data);
}
getCommonData(): Observable<BehaviorSubject<any>> {
  return this.commonData;
}
```

***app.component.ts***

```
// result = {id: number, name: string, info: {}}
getData(): void {
    this.dataService.getApi(url, {}, true).subscribe((result) => {
        this.sharedService.setCommonData(result);
    }
}
```

***child.component.ts***

```
displayData(): void {
    this.sharedService.getCommonData().subscribe((data) => {
         this.displatData = data // works
         this.info = data.info // property info does not exist on type 'BehaviourSubject<any>'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning an observable of the `BehaviorSubject`. Instead you need to return the `BehaviorSubject` *as* an observable.

Try the following

```js
setCommonData(data): void {
  this.commonData.next(data);
}

getCommonData(): Observable<any> {         // <-- return `Observable` here
  return this.commonData.asObservable();
}
```